# Entity Framework Core, execute raw SQL and parameterize table name

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core and when I run the following query it all works as expected and selects all entities from the `flasher_equipment` table.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<BaseEquipmentType>> GetNewAvailableEquipment(string tableName)
{
    DbSet<BaseEquipmentType> dbSet = _context.Set<BaseEquipmentType>();
    IQueryable<BaseEquipmentType> types = dbSet.FromSql($"select * from flasher_equipment");
    return await types.ToArrayAsync();
}
```

but now, instead of hard coding the table name (`flasher_equipment`) I want to pass it as a parameter.

I've tried changing the code as follows:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<BaseEquipmentType>> GetNewAvailableEquipment(string tableName)
{
    DbSet<BaseEquipmentType> dbSet = _context.Set<BaseEquipmentType>();
    IQueryable<BaseEquipmentType> types = dbSet.FromSql($"select * from {tableName}");
    return await types.ToArrayAsync();
}
```

and I've also tried

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<BaseEquipmentType>> GetNewAvailableEquipment(string tableName)
{
    DbSet<BaseEquipmentType> dbSet = _context.Set<BaseEquipmentType>();
    IQueryable<BaseEquipmentType> types = dbSet.FromSql("select * from {0}", tableName);
    return await types.ToArrayAsync();
}
```

Each time I get an error:

> Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler[6]
> Error when executing service method 'GetByPlanIdAnImplementation'.
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00903: invalid table name

Why is parameterizing the table name as a parameter causing it to crash?

Comment: But why do you want to parameterize table name? Your future self is shooting himself in a leg.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an problem of the `FromSql` [method with the string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#previous-versions).

Probably it will work if you interpolate the string outside the method, as:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<BaseEquipmentType>> GetNewAvailableEquipment(string tableName)
{
    DbSet<BaseEquipmentType> dbSet = _context.Set<BaseEquipmentType>();
    string sqlStatement = $"select * from {tableName}"; 
    IQueryable<BaseEquipmentType> types = dbSet.FromSql(sqlStatement);
    return await types.ToArrayAsync();
}
```

Comment: That does make it work, but visual studio shows a warning saying the expression passed to FromSQL embeds data that will not be parameterized. Potenetial SQL Injection Vulnerability. 
I assume this will be fine though?

Comment: I was aware of that. It will be fine. It's just a warning.
But, I would advise to change it in the future, to the new version of the EF Core